# Old windows program running through wine fail to load library

Tags: wine

A program called Megamud is crashing when I attempt to run it with `wine megamud.exe`, in the terminal I'm getting:

```
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The application is telling me Your INI file does not appear to be within "Chars" sub-directory. Please check that the correct INI file has been loaded and that MegaMud is installed properly.

I'm not sure if I'm supposed to be ignoring the terminal error and focusing on the wine one or not.  But in the past I've installed and run this with ease on older releases of ubuntu/wine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running a 64 bit Ubuntu? Maybe you are missing the compatibility library.

I cannot check your application, but in my system:

```
[romano:~] % locate gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so
```

So I have just the 64-bit version. Let's see which package correspond to it:

```
apt-file search /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so
libp11-kit-gnome-keyring: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so
```

...and install the i386 version:

```
sudo apt-get install libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386
```

...that should get rid of the first problem. I do not know about the Wine one...

Comment: Yeah I'm using 64 bit, I'll try that,

Comment: @daniel, if this solved the problem, please mark the answer as accepted: http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: sorry forgot to